# Удаление текста между тегами

Tags: delphi

Данная функция обрабатывает отлично текст но к примеру:
Если нужно удалить текст между тегами **t1 и тут текст /t1** то работает нормально.

А вот если нужно удалить текст между тегами **t1 и тут текст t1** (то есть между одинаковыми тегами) то удаляет только теги **t1** а все что между ними оставляет. **Как можно это исправить ?**

```
function test(s,mask1,mask2:string):string;
var  p1,p2:Word;
begin
repeat
p1:=Pos(mask1,s);
p2:=Pos(mask2,s);
Delete(s,p1,p2-p1+length(mask2));
until (p1=0)or(p2=0);
Result:=s;
end;
```

Comment: для данных целей проще вообще применить регулярные выражения

Comment: @Igor, А как в вашем варианте кода сделать так что бы теги (слова) между которых удаляется текст оставались, ну а сам текст между ними удалялся?. Если это возможно ?

Comment: @Igor, В этом варианте (Delete), при обработке, программа просто зависает. Что может быть ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысл - второй тег ищем в строке, начинающейся там, где кончается первый тег.

*(Проверки на присутствие и относительное расположение тегов в исходной строке опущены для простоты.)*

```
function test(s, mask1, mask2: string): string;
var
  p1, p2: Word;
  sAfterMask1: string;
  mask1Length: integer;
begin
  mask1Length := Length(mask1);
  repeat
    p1 := Pos(mask1,s);
    sAfterMask1 := Copy(s, p1 + mask1Length, Length(s) - p1 + mask1Length - 1);
    p2 := Pos(mask2, sAfterMask1) + p1 + mask1Length - 1;
    //Delete(s, p1, p2 - p1 + Length(mask2));
    Delete(s, p1 + mask1Length, p2 - p1 + Length(mask2)); // не ошибся ли я здесь на 1?
  until (p1 = 0) or (p2 = 0);
  Result := s;
end;
```

Comment: С Вашей правкой - Вы, мне, намного упростили работу. Что очень приятно. Я даже и не думала что так можно оформить код. Всегда благодарна Вам Igor.

Comment: А как в вашем варианте кода сделать так что бы теги (слова) между которых удаляется текст оставались, ну а сам текст между ними удалялся?. Если это возможно ?

Comment: @Татьяна Посмотрите на другой вариант вызова `Delete`.

Comment: В этом варианте (Delete), при обработке, программа просто зависает. Что может быть ?

Comment: Вместо `sAfterMask1 := Copy(s,...` и следующего `p2 := Pos(...` можно использовать [`PosEx()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.StrUtils.PosEx) специально для этого предназначенную...